# Getting empty CSV files

Tags: csv, groovy, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to write hashmap data into CSV files but I see empty files being generated. Here is the following code that I am using:

```
String fileName
    for (String key : concurrentHashMap.keySet()) {
        logInfo(key + ": ")//gives the name of the file
        logInfo("concurrentHashMapKey" + concurrentHashMap.get(key))
        fileName = key
        logInfo("fileName: " + fileName)
        helpers.writeHashMapToCsv(concurrentHashMap, fileName)
    }

public void writeHashMapToCsv(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collectedCSV, String fileName) throws Exception {
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator")
        try{
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(".\\baseline-files\\" + fileName)
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : collectedCSV.entrySet()) {
                println "entry = $entry"
                writer.append(entry.getKey())
                        .append(',')
                        .append(entry.getValue())
                        .append(eol)
            }
        } catch (IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err)
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong here?

Note:
concurrentHashMap Size =2

concurrentHashMap = [NetworkLeakage_Main_crosstab.csv:      % of Total Total Payments No Pro along Serv Netwk, Site Type    Total Payments No Pro
Home Health Out Of Network  1%  $247,870
Home Health Owned   6%  $1,306,259
Skilled Nursing Facility    Out Of Network  4%  $860,545
Skilled Nursing Facility    Owned   18% $3,919,193
, IP_RehabSNF_Profiles_crosstab.csv:Facility    Site Type   Network Affiliation Number of Episodes  Total Payment   % of Total Payment  Mean Episode Payment    ALOS    CMS Rating
LORRETTA HOSPITAL   Anchor  Owned   28  $344,392    2%  $12,300 3
LORRETTA HOSPITAL   Home Health Out Of Network  87  $14,358 0%  $2,872
LORRETTA HOSPITAL   Home Health Owned   19  $2,981  0%  $2,981
LORRETTA HOSPITAL   Outpatient  Out Of Network  77  $3,706  0%  $71
LORRETTA HOSPITAL   Outpatient  Owned   1,593   $149,194    1%  $288
]

So there are 2 sets of keys (file names) and values (data) present here for which I need to genereate follwoing 2 files:
1. NetworkLeakage_Main_crosstab.csv

2. IP_RehabSNF_Profiles_crosstab.csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Write hashmap to a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172003/java-write-hashmap-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: If you are using groovy, simplest way to deal with csv's - https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `writer.close()` as your `Writer` buffers data.

It is best to add it to the `finally` block:

```
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err)
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to change:

```
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(".\\baseline-files\\" + fileName)
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : collectedCSV.entrySet()) {
            println "entry = $entry"
            writer.append(entry.getKey())
                    .append(',')
                    .append(entry.getValue())
                    .append(eol)
        }
```

To

```
        new File("./baseline-files/$fileName").withWriter { writer ->
            collectedCSV.each { key, value ->
                writer.writeLine "$key,$value"
            }
        }
```

This will close the writer for you automatically